# How to order queryset based on best match in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to **order** results of a query with parameters **by number of matches**.

For example, let's say we have a Model:

```
class Template(models.Model):
    headline = CharField(max_length=300)
    text = TextField()
    image_text = TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedItem)
    ...
```

With a Serializer:

```
class TemplateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = (...)
```

And a ViewSet:

```
class TemplateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Templates to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Template.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TemplateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Template.objects.all()

        tags = self.request.query_params.getlist('tags', None)
        search_text = self.request.query_params.getlist('search_text', None)

        if tags is not None:
            queries = [Q(groost_tags__name__iexact=tag) for tag in tags]
            query = queries.pop()
            for item in queries:
                query |= item

            queryset = queryset.filter(query).distinct()

        if search_tags is not None:
            queries = [Q(image_text__icontains=string) |
                       Q(text__icontains=string) |
                       Q(headline__icontains=string) for string in search_tags]
            query = queries.pop()
            for item in queries:
                query |= item

            queryset = queryset.filter(query).distinct()
```

What I need to do is count every match the filter finds and then order the queryset by that number of matches for each template. For example:

I want to find all the templates that have *"hello"* and *"world"* strings in their text, image_text or headline. So I set the query parameter *"search_text"* to *hello,world*. Template with *headline="**World**"* and *text="**Hello**, everyone."* would have **2 matches**. Another one with *headline="**Hello**"* would have **1 match**. The template with 2 matches would be the *first* in the queryset. The same behaviour should work for *tags* and *tags* with *search_text* **combined**.

I tried to calculate these numbers right in the ViewSet and then return a *sorted(queryset, key=attrgetter('matches'))* but encountered several issues with the DRF, like *Template has no attribute 'matches'.* Or 404 when directly accessing a Template instance through API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to `annotation` where each matching pair returns 1 or 0 that are summarized into rank:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg, Case, F, FloatField, Value, When

Template.objects.annotate(
    k1=Case(
        When(image_text__icontains=string, then=Value(1.0)),
        default=Value(0.0),
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
    k2=Case(
        When(text__icontains=string, then=Value(1.0)),
        default=Value(0.0),
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
    k3=Case(
        When(headline__icontains=string, then=Value(1.0)),
        default=Value(0.0),
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
    rank=F("k1") + F("k2") + F("k3"),
).order_by("-rank")
```

Comment: Genius! I thought annotation is the way but i did not know how to achieve the right behaviour. But one more question. Tags is a list of tags. How to do this but for lists, not strings? That means, order by the best match in a list. If *tags=hello, world*, then a template with *tags=hello*, world would be first and a template with *tags=hello* would be second.

Comment: Did you look at non Django solutions? Elasticsearch, Solr or Sphinx could help in that case with configurable weightings.

Comment: Not yet, as I thought this can be solved completely using django. But I will give it a try, thanks!